# ceil(double(int)*double) or ceil(float(int*double))?

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy, ceil

I had this C++ code:

```
int x;
double y;

// do sth

int z = ceil(x*y);
```

If `x = 410`, `y = 1.1`, then `z = 452` when it should've been `451`. I changed to `z = ceil(float(x*y))` and it works. My friend suggests `z = ceil(double(x)*y)` instead. Are there any differences between the 2 definition of `z` and which one should I use?

Also what does `x*y` do? I suspect it is equivalent to `float(x)*y` but I'm not so sure.

Comment: `x*y` is same as `double(x)*y`. It might be easier to understand if you print floating-point variables with max precision: `std::cout << std::setprecision(1000) << y << '\n'.`. Some decimal fractions can't be represented exactly in floating-point, so `1.1` is actually `1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625`.

Comment: Summary: IEEE-754 is largely design for approximating well-behaved continuous functions. (Well-behaved includes not having large derivatives.) `ceil` is not a continuous function. Using discontinuous functions in floating-point code risks turning small rounding errors into large errors.

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### How this all works

`x * y` simply multiplies the two variables. This implicitly does a type conversion, in this case converting the int value of `410` to the double value `410.0` (because `y` is a double) before doing the actual multiplication.

Because of this type conversion, your friend's suggestion is just a more explicit version of what your original code does. It yields the same result, i.e. it will give `452`.

### The answer to your question

> If x = 410, y = 1.1, then z = 452 when it should've been 451

True, by real world calculus. However, doubles and floats in computers have finite precision. If you print with increased precision:

```cpp
printf("%.15f\n", (x * y)); // -> 451.000000000000057
```

You'll agree that when `ceil`ing this, it yields `452`.
The reason `ceil(float(x * y))` works is entirely by accident; because a [`float` has lower precision than a `double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), this happens to round `x * y` to `451.000000...`.

You can't rely on floating point arithmetic to produce exactly the results you'd expect in the real world, and the `ceil` can make that very much apparent in scenario's like the one you give.
Without further information on the underlying problem you're trying to solve, I can't give further direction on what you could do.

Comment: Obligatory nitpick that a "cast" is by definition an explicit conversion. In this case the conversion is implicit, i.e. not a cast.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!